# Using state variables inside an interval callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm developing a small multiplayer web game where the player sends answer to some questions within a time limit.

I have this state "answer" which is used by an input to be the same as the content of the input field:

```
const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("")
return (
    <>
        {/*...*/}
        <input  type="text"
                value={answer}
                onInput={e => setAnswer(e.target.value)}/>
        {/*...*/}
    </>
)
```

And a button to send the answer before the timer rings:

```
<div onClick={() => {sendAnswer(false)}}>
```

The function "sendAnswer" is used to actually send whatever the player wrote in that input field to the server along with some others states, using the data inside "answer" state. This function is declared inside the component function like that:

```
function GameRound() {
    // ...
    const sendAnswer = async (autoSent) => {
        // ...
        fetch("...endpoint...", {
            // ...
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "answer": answer,
                "ready": !autoSent,
                "timeRemaining": timerTime
            })
        });
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

I also have an interval decreasing the timer var, which is initialized inside a useEffect on [] and will call "sendAnswer" when it reaches 0

### The problem

When the player triggers "sendAnswer" by clicking on the button, everything is ok and the body of the server request matches the actual data of the states variable used. But when "sendAnswer" is triggered by the interval, the data passed to the reqeust body is just the initial values set to the states when creating them with useState.

I think it's because of the "sendAnswer" callback outside an hook but, I can't find another way!

EDIT: my useEffect

```
const [timerTime, setTimerTime] = useState(30);

useEffect(() => {
    const updateTimer = () => {
        setTimerTime((oldTimerTime) => {
            if(oldTimerTime === 1) {
                if(canSendRef.current)
                    sendAnswer(true)
            }
            return oldTimerTime-1
        });
    };

    timerInterval = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
}, [sharedEventSource])
```

Comment: Can't figure out that are they different Comps or files ?

Comment: Can you please share your useEffect

Comment: @ALFaizAhmed its just one file, same component, I showed you just some minimal snippets because its acutally more complex than that

Comment: And `sharedEventSource` source that's part of your useEffect dependency doesn't change right? Its the same thing for all renders?

Comment: @NickParsons yeah its the same, its the shared eventsource to get sse events from the server got from useContext

Comment: @Crih.exe Is `sendAnswer` defined in the same component that your `useEffect` is in? or are you passing it as props to the component that uses it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257018/discussion-between-crih-exe-and-nick-parsons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, your `useEffect()` callback function is created on the initial mount of your `GameRound` component and sets up the interval. The `useEffect()` callback function knows about the variables in its surrounding scope, which includes things like state and functions (ie: `sendAnswer`). However, since your `useEffect()` dependency doesn't ever change across rerenders (based on your comments), the useEffect callback function is only invoked once on mount, and so it only knows about the state and functions created for that initial render where your state values all hold their initial values. And so, all the code nested within the callback only ever "sees" the variable values from the initial render/invocation of your function component (this is often referred to as a stale closure).

The typical way to get around this is to pass `sendAnswer` as a dependency to your `useEffect()`, however, this will cause all sorts of issues with the timer stopping and starting as you change your `answer` state. Unfortunately, the best way to get around this is [yet to be officially released](https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects#declaring-an-effect-event) into React. However, for the time being, we can create a hook that mimics this yet-to-be-implemented feature ourselves by creating a custom pseudo version of the `useEffectEvent` hook:

```js
// Rough example of how `useEffectEvent` could be implemented.
// Taken from: https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md#internal-implementation
import { useRef, useLayoutEffect, useCallback } from "react";
function useEffectEvent(handler) {
  const handlerRef = useRef(null);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    handlerRef.current = handler;
  });
  return useCallback((...args) => {
    const fn = handlerRef.current;
    return fn(...args);
  }, []);
}
```

Now to use it, I would first suggest you look at avoiding putting side effects into your state setter function. As you mentioned in your comment below, your interval is added by an event handler.
You can refactor your `useEffect` callback a little to something like this:

```js
const decTimer = useEffectEvent(() => {
  if (timerTime === 1 && canSendRef.current);
    sendAnswer(true);
  
  setTimerTime(oldTimerTime => oldTimerTime-1); // no side-effects anymore (your state setter function is now a pure function, as React recommends).
});

useEffect(() => {
  let timerInterval;
  sharedEventSource.addEventListener("game", (event) => {
    timerInterval = setInterval(() => decTimer(), 1000);
  });

  return () => {
    sharedEventSource.removeEventListener("game");
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
  };

}, [sharedEventSource]); // no need to specify `decTimer` as a dependency as it is stable across renders (same function reference for every rerender)
```

With this setup `canSendRef.current` can also remain as state (rather than a ref), as now `decTimer` has access to the most up-to-date state.

Comment: thanks a lot! BTW I'd have a question on the side note. The code I provided is simplified as I omitted that in my useEffect, I'm using the sharedEventSource to add an event listener on "game" events, which is the event coming from the server telling the client to start the round and so the interval. So, the timerInterval is set inside that event listener. Will adding timerTime to the dependencies cause problems with the listener as it will trigger ```sharedEventSource.addEventListener("game", (event) => {...setInterval()...}``` every second?